# How to get AppCenter Crash Attachments to work

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, visual-studio-app-center

I easily attach log files to errors, but with crashes I have problems and the documentation is very poor in my opinion. The code snippet below is what I am using (which is also straight from documentation).

```
Crashes.GetErrorAttachments = _ =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetErrorAttachments called");
    var test = GetCompressedLogs();
    return new ErrorAttachmentLog[]
    {
        ErrorAttachmentLog.AttachmentWithBinary(test.ToArray(), "logs.zip", "application/x-zip-compressed")
    };
};
```

I am not sure if my placement of this code snippet is what is making it unable to be called? If someone could help that would be great. In my device log that `Console.WriteLine()` piece never gets printed and of course the logs are never visible on app center either.